# Failing to fetch debian from ruby 2.4.3

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian

In my Dockerfile, these lines

```
FROM ruby:2.4.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
```

Are producing the following error:

```
 => ERROR [ 2/11] RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs   14.3s
------                                                                                                   > [ 2/11] RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs:               
#0 11.41 W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]                                                                 
#0 11.41                                                                                                
#0 11.41 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 11.41 
#0 11.41 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 11.41 
#0 11.41 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs]: exit code: 100
```

I have tried setting the /etc/apt/sources.list, but this and nothing else have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.